# The server did not preserve SSL encryption during a recovery attempt, connection recovery is not possible

Tags: sql-server, ssl

We are starting to get the error message

```
The server did not preserve SSL encryption during a recovery attempt, connection recovery is not possible
```

from our MS SQL Server 2019 15.0.4298.1 instance. We have never seen this error before, and are at a loss as to what caused it.

The Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/idle-connection-resiliency?view=sql-server-2017 states that this is one of the errors that can occur when connection recovery is not possible, but it does not mention why connection recovery may not be possible. Also, we are starting to see this issue just recently.

We "fixed" it by setting the retry attempts to 0, thus switching off connection resiliency, which works for our system. But we don't know if we just masked a deeper core problem that will bite us later.

Are there any current updates or other changes that are known to create conditions where connection recovery is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

> [...] but it does not mention why connection recovery may not be possible.

From the [Doc about Connection Resiliency](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/0/D20E1C5F-72EA-4505-9F26-FEF9550EFD44/Idle%20Connection%20Resiliency.docx)

> Special treatment is given for handling SSL encryption during reconnect.  The client and server negotiate if SSL encryption is enabled for the connection during initial connection establishment.  In general, the client verifies that the same encryption level (either on or off) is used on the recovered connection, otherwise it fails the recovery.

---

> But we don't know if we just masked a deeper core problem that will bite us later.

Hard to say since we have no data. You'd want to trace the connection on the client and server side and see why this occurred.

> Are there any current updates or other changes that are known to create conditions where connection recovery is not possible?

I'd download the Doc I linked above as it has more items and no reason to copy/pasta here.

Answer (score 0):

When I connected to a database, I checked the Options>>Connection Properties and clicked the Encrypt connection and Trust Server Certificate boxes.   This resolved my issues.